# Ink Stains Removal Therapy

Tags: stain

Last week, my gel pen leaked in my shirt's pocket, colouring it black.

Is there any way to remove these stains?

Comment: Was the shirt washed yet or treated with anything? What brand of gel pen? What other information was on the pen label?

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of sanitizer (yea, the one you use to clean you hands!) Just apply some in the ink stain and wash, and apply again and wash, Boom! Stain's gone!

Alternative; 
Dip the stained portion in milk overnight, wash in the Morning,it'll surely go!

Answer (score 1):

Ethanol, as in hand sanitizer, as @QuestionEverything sugeests, is an effective first step. However, to get "black" ink, a number of different dyes are used, so other solvents may be needed in order to remove residual colors. In order, I'd try:

- Ethanol or isopropanol. Since hand cleaner is usually ~70% ethanol, 90% or more isopropanol, found in most pharmacies, is better. Caution, flammable.
- Acetone or methyl ethyl ketone, which are in nail polish remover. Caution, flammable.
- Diethyl ether, used in car starter sprays. Caution, **extremely** flammable.
- Xylene or toluene, sold as paint thinner or stripper. Caution, flammable and toxic.

Finally, if it's a white shirt and can withstand it, a bit of bleach in a lot of water.

Answer (score 0):

I used Wd-40 on my carpet and left it for a couple of minutes and then I used warm water to rinse it. It worked very well. Try using this on your pocket.